# http2 push link rel=reload not working in simple html

Tags: http2

I have the following simple html code running on Apache/2.4.29 (codeit):

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="preload" href="/test.css" as="style">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
```

Why does the browser show Initiator html, but not Push?

[image: image here]

Answer (score 1):

Apache only uses the Link HTTP Header to push resources - not Link information in the HTML file itself.

So you need to add this to your Apache config:

```
Header add Link "</test.css>;rel=preload;as=style"
```

Alternatively if generating pages dynamically in some downstream system (e.g. PHP, Node or Tomcat) then they can add the HTTP Header, and Apache will see them when sending the response back and push the resources appropriately.

You should also consider whether to push every time or only if the asset is not already set. I’ve a simple method to do this based on a cookie here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http2/http2-push/

Comment: thank you for response! am I correct understand from above link that with PHP it can be used to set headers , rather than Apache itself? - If you are using other technology behind Apache, to generate the pages (e.g. PHP or an App server such as Jboss, Tomcat, Node...etc.), then you can use them to set the headers appropriately, rather than Apache itself, and Apache should read those headers when sending the response and push appropriately.

Comment: Correct. Answer updated to include this information.